# hyperledger explorer not starting with Fabcar app

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Explorer is not starting with Fabcar sample application. I have configured config.json and change connection profile to fabcar. I am using default connection setting available in connection-profile/fabcar.jason.But while starting blockchain explorer it giving me below error.

2019-11-30T09:44:53.671Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
Error : Failed to connect client peer, please check the configuration and peer status

Answer (score 0):

Did you start a network before? If so, try to remove the **crypto-config** and **channel-artifacts** folders and rerun. When you start a network should not be crypto material from other before

Comment: No luck..still same error.. I don`t see anyone using fabcar in explorer